# Webpack Binding Issue

Tags: node.js, windows, webpack

Hey guys for some reason I keep getting this error when building with sass-loader

Module build failed: Error: Missing binding C:\TFS_Local\DPOnGit\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-11\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 32-bit with Node 0.10.x
Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 5.x
This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.

Very frustrating as this config has worked on the same machine before without issues.

Comment: Did you try rebuilding node-sass as suggested? If you have upgraded Node, then you'll need to recompile library dependencies like this. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Yes, I did try that to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node Sass couldn't find a binding for your current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986800/node-sass-couldnt-find-a-binding-for-your-current-environment)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, rebuilding as suggested by the error message didn't work for me, but running

```
npm install --save sass-loader
```

did.