# Node Sass couldn't find a binding for your current environment

Tags: node.js, npm

I am having issues building an app because node-sass keeps failing with the error.

> ERROR in Missing binding /Users/warren/Sites/random-docs/my-cms/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-11/binding.node
>   Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node 0.10.x

I have tried running

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

which says

> Binary is fine; exiting.

When running `node -v` I get v6.2.2

Which is different to what the sass error says "Node 0.10.x". I can't figure out why it is getting the wrong version. I have also tried removing the node_modules folder and running npm update or npm install, both of which did not resolve the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a node version manager such as `nvm`? If you are sometimes it messes up some of the npm module paths and they try using a version, different that the current one. If not you could always try removing the `node_modules` folder and installing the dependencies again

Comment: Hey im not using nvm and I tried the removal/re-install step. no luck.

Comment: what is your development environment?  you use  VS.NET 2105?

Comment: @VasilDininski I'm using nvm, what should I do?

Comment: What error message did you receive? And what is your dev environment?

Comment: Have you tried removing your `~/.node-gyp` or `~/.npm` folder? Mentioned below.

Comment: I've tried deleting the `node_modules` directory and also running `npm install`, followed by `npm rebuild node-sass --force`, but to of no avail. I installed node via npm. But, for some reason, my build environment thinks I need a Linux build even though I'm running on Mac OS X: 
     ```Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /frontend/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
     Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

    Found bindings for the following environments:
      - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 8.x```

Comment: Open Visual Studio 2017 Go to Tools -> Options…Go to Projects and Solutions -> Web Package Management move $(PATH) to the top of that list and close that window. In my case this solution worked because my node version is 11.x

Comment: Very much late . As I got this issue today only after I update my system nodejs version in windows 10. I removed both node_modules folder and the package_lock.json from work directory and run npm install and it starts working.

Comment: npm rebuild node-sass 
Works for me on MacOS

Answer (score 976):

**I had the same problem**

> There is an error in your gulpfile:
> Error: Missing binding E:\allapp\badshaindiancuisine\node_module\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-46\binding.node
> Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment:Windows 64-bit with Node.js 4.x
>
> Found bindings for the following environment:
>     - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 4.x

**How to solve the problem**

By going into the project folder and then executing the command:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: Worked initially but was still having problems. So, I went to `/usr/local/lib/` using CMD+SHIFT+G in finder and renamed node-sass folder. Then ran `npm install node-sass -g`. that fixed. I'm on Mac OS

Comment: I was facing this issue after updating nodejs to 8.x.x and this solved it.
Thanks much! Appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't work.  Node: `v10.7.0`  node-sass: `v3.13.1`.  Says my current environment is 32 bit windows with node 0.10.x which is simply not true.

Comment: This worked in windows 7 with node 10.14 LTS and npm 6.4.1.

Comment: Worked for me. I think I upgraded node the other day and consequently node-sass stopped working. I ran `npm rebuild node-sass` and it worked.

Comment: Didn't work for me - rebuilding just said it was fine and exited

Comment: First step would be to delete your `node_modules` and run `npm install` rather than rebuilding your node-sass.

Comment: This worked for me without any extra steps, Thanks!

Comment: Problem persisted after `npm rebuild node-sass`. However, `npm uninstall node-sass` then `npm install node-sass` worked for me.

Comment: what should I do if using yarn?

Comment: Don't forget to remove `package-lock.json` too!!!

Comment: worked. any explanation on what it does?

Answer (score 366):

**For those that are using Visual Studio:**

Currently working for VS 2015, 2017, 2019, 2022 (via below and/or replies from this post)

[Task Runner Explorer can't load tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301582/task-runner-explorer-cant-load-tasks/31444245)

**For VS 2015**

- Go to: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools

**For VS 2017(.3), VS 2019, and VS 2022**

- Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools  (per @nothrow)

> In VS 2017, 2019, 2022, you also need to put $(PATH) above $(VSINSTALLERDIR)\Web\External

---

- Reorder so that $(PATH) is above $(DevEnvDir)\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External

[image]

---

Deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install` and then `npm rebuild node-sass` **did nothing**.

Comment: If you are using VS2015 you should definitely make the changes described in this answer. It's probably all you will need to do to fix this issue.

Comment: This also worked for a brand new install of VS2017 also.

Comment: This fixed by issue. @wazzaday I believe this should be the accepted answer for others to find the answer easily.

Comment: In VS2017.3, the path to the setting is `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools`

Comment: This worked out for me also. I'm running VS Professional 2015

Comment: This fixed my issue (and the rest of my dev team has come across this - I've had some rollback to 5.0 node just to get this working).

Comment: Fantastic answer, I've been having issues with VS2017 and where is grabs external pieces.

Comment: damn!i would never figure it out... all to compile stupid sass with stupid node in stupid javascript

Comment: This worked for me after deleting node_modules from the project. (Running VS2017)

Comment: If creating a docker image, and receiving this error during the docker build, you must ensure you didn't accidentally include a node_modules directory from your host drive. You need to have a .dockerignore file containing an exclusion for 'node_modules', otherwise those files from your hist will be copied into the container during a 'copy . .' command. The when building a node project in the container which is most likely based off a different underlying Os image, it will attempt using the binding node which was copied in from the host OS - which is obviously the wrong one.

Comment: Can confirm, this is still a thing in VS 2019.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to move environment variables above VS extensions

Comment: Deleting node_modules really helped.

Comment: Not sure why using node in VS is so difficult, with this many gotchas. Spent hours on this issue; tried everything until I moved the path above the external tools. The errors in Task Runner Explorer gave no indication of the underlying problem.

Comment: Still a thing in VS2022 as well (Preview 4, at least)

Answer (score 193):

---

**Just execute: **  `npm rebuild node-sass --force`

---

If the above for some reason didn't work out for you, try this:

1. Delete `node-sass` folder under `node_modules`
2. `npm install`

---

In my case it also couldn't find `Python`.

**Following procedure solved the issue (Windows):**

```
npm rebuild node-sass --force
-- cannot find python.exe, if you have Python installed, add it to your path:
set PYTHON=C:\Python27\Python.exe
-- else: download python "Windows x86-64-MSI" installer from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2714/
-- install python
-- at installation start check: add env variable to path
-- after successfull installation:
npm rebuild node-sass --force
-- finished successfully
```

Comment: The above worked for me, albeit that it occurred twice in two different apps in two different folders. The python install was a one-off (i.e.not needed when I got the error a second time on my other app) and I didn't need the final npm run build command (not explicitly at least) but I did need to run the rebuild --force twice for both my apps.

Comment: Rebuild need more then 10 minutes on my Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 170):

Worked for me:

Just delete the node-sass folder and run `npm install`.

Comment: This works for me too. Clearly a node version conflict. Thanks!

Comment: Did have to delete it the following directory: C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

Comment: This worked! `npm rebuild node-sass` did not work for me. (Mac with WebStorm)

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me! ```npm rebuild node-sass --force``` didn't work either.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Until now I had no idea why my solution kept targeting a higher version of node and kept giving me error message about nodesass. I had a step in the Azure pipeline to force the node version to the one I want. Now I can removed that step!

Comment: npm uninstall node-sass followed by npm install node-sass and finally adding the python.exe file with directory to the env Path variable

Answer (score 154):

I had the same problem in a Windows environment, receiving the following error:

> Error: Missing binding C:\Development{ProjectName}\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-47\binding.node
>   Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 32-bit with Node.js 5.x
>   Found bindings for the following environments:
>      - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

None of the `npm` commands listed in the other answers here (`npm install`, `npm rebuild node-sass`, etc.) worked.

Instead, I had to download the missing binding and place it in the appropriate destination folder.

The bindings can be found [on git](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-binaries).  Match the file with the folder name identified after `/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/` in your error message ('darwin-x64-11' in your case, so you'd want the `darwin-x64-11_binding.node` file).

Create the missing folder in your project (`/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-11`), copy the `.node` file to the new directory, and rename it to `binding.node`.

Node-sass release URL:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases

Comment: Also worked for me, thanks! Tried cleaning up node_modules, deleting cache, rifraf, rebuild node-sass, rebuild from VS2015 instead of from command line with npm and at the end this fixed it.

Comment: I had to place to file in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-57\

Comment: And each time you set up your project you must redo?seems a bit cumbersome

Comment: @JanCiołek I only had this happen once, so I never had to redo this.  I'm not sure if it was version specific, or if there was just a problem with the specific install, but I found no better solution (the other answers here did not work for me).  Cumbersome or not, it seemed to be the necessary solution for some variations of this problem.

Comment: @Beofett This bug ate alot of my time,i did all that was mentioned in this thread but i forget to run compilation.Thanks !

Comment: This is the only answer that worker for me, but found my binding in https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases instead of the linked URL. Cheers

Comment: My error says 'linux-x64-57/binding.node' which is not available on the git url that you posted. update: found it :)

Comment: Thank you @Beofett. Your answer saved me to run my Ionic project in Windows and Mac OSX.

Comment: I tried using that and now it tells me that it could not find the bindings even though one line later it stated that it found them...

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me - On Linux 64 with Node 12.6. For some reason, node-sass wanted the binding for Node 8.x. I had to manually create the linux-x64-57 folder, download the binary binding.node, and copy it into that folder.

Comment: thanks! this seems a bit "hacky", but as long as it works I'm a happy camper :)

Comment: This also work for me but when you reinstall the node_modules folder you will have the same issue right?

Answer (score 40):

I had a similar problem and the reason was that there were two versions of Node installed in my machine: one "global" and another one at the project level.
Sass will build correctly only if the Gulp build is running under Node.js 4.x version, so make sure you upgrade the version of Node you are using.

PS: If you completely remove the **node_modules** folder in your project and re-build from scratch, npm will download the correct dependencies for your current system & node version.

Comment: thank god for this. I actually tried to downgrade node on my macbook first and then gave up after half an hour

Answer (score 40):

`npm rebuild node-sass --force`

Or, if you are using node-sass within a container:

`docker exec <container-id> npm rebuild node-sass --force`

This error occurs when node-sass does not have the correct binding for the current operating system.

If you use Docker, this error usually happens when you add `node_modules` directly to the container filesystem in your Dockerfile (or mount them using a Docker volume).

The container architecture is probably different than your current operating system. For example, I installed node-sass on macOS but my container runs Ubuntu.

If you force node-sass to rebuild from within the container, node-sass will download the correct bindings for the container operating system.

See [my repro case](https://github.com/shcallaway/node-sass-docker-bug) to learn more.

Comment: Facing the same issue with different environments:
- dev under MacOS for unit tests
- dev using docker-compose (for full system interactions)
- prod under alpine-based OS ; 
Mounting (or not) and `npm install` (or not) in docker is problematic when having architecture dependent modules: getting *darwin* or *linux* binaries depending on where you `npm i`
It happens for NodeJS modules like `node-sass`, or `@google-cloud/pubsub`

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the solution for docker, this is exactly what fixed it for me!

Comment: I had `/node_modules` which was being bind mounted into the container at `/app/node_modules`. Even though my `NODE_PATH` was `/node_modules` (which did exist) and should have been in a different spot.., it randomly started causing issues. I had installed at both places so that my dev deps for prettier would work with my vscode. whoops. weird stuff. Thank you for the docker mention <3

Comment: I found this worked after deleting /node_modules/, then running 'npm install' then your command 'npm rebuild node-sass --force'

Answer (score 25):

`node-sass` node module uses `darwin` binary file which is dependent on the version of node. This issue occurs when the binary file is not downloaded or wrong binary file is downloaded.

[![Node sass error][1]][1]

Reinstall node modules will download expected binary of node-sass:-

**For Mac users:**

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm i
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

**For Windows users:**

```
rmdir node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm i
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

but for some users, you need to check your node version's compatibility with node-sass version. Make it compatible using below table and run above commands again to fix this issue.

This is node compatibility table with node-sass

```
NodeJS | Supported node-sass version | Node Module
Node 19     8.0+                        111
Node 18     8.0+                        108
Node 17     7.0+                        102
Node 16     6.0+                        93
Node 15     5.0+                        88
Node 14     4.14+                       83
Node 13     4.13+, <5.0                 79
Node 12     4.12+                       72
Node 11     4.10+, <5.0                 67
Node 10     4.9+, <6.0                  64
Node 8      4.5.3+, <5.0                57
Node <8     <5.0                        <57
```

If issue is still not fixed, check node-sass supported environment's list:- https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/

Comment: Also, if you clone others project you need to change the node in your package.json to your current node version.

Answer (score 21):

in some cases you need to uninstall and install node-sass library. Try:

```
npm uninstall --save node-sass
```

and

```
npm install --save node-sass
```

look at this its work for me,
[Stack link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324519/node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-linux-64-bit-with-false)

Answer (score 20):

*** Docker related answer here ***

Answer for if you are seeing this problem, or something similar, and are using Docker.

Cause: When copying over the current file structure to inside the Docker container, you may be copying over node modules from one OS system to another (e.g. a Mac to Linux container).

Solution:

Add a `.dockerignore`, and inside add:

`node_modules`

This will cause an `npm install` to install the bindings for the docker environment, rather than your local machine environment.

Comment: Can someone elaborate this answer? This is something I needed, but it would be helpful if anyone can explain this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

If your terminal/command prompt says:

```
Node Sass could not find a binding 
for your current environment: 
OS X 64-bit with Node 0.10.x
```

and you have tried the following commands such as:

```
npm cache clean --force 
rm -rf node_modules 
npm install 
npm rebuild node-sass
```

& still NOTHING works..

Just run this in the terminal manually:

```
node node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js
```

now run

```
npm start or yarn start
```

Comment: Finally! Thank you. This is the only solution worked for me so far. I've been struggling for two days. Could you please explain what is the reason behind?

Comment: YES YES YES!  Finally!  Jackie - Thank you soooooo much.

Comment: should be `rm -rf node_modules`

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem

```
    throw new Error(errors.missingBinary());
    ^

Error: Missing binding /path/to/project/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-47/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 5.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 64-bit with Node 0.10.x
  - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 5.x
```

That was because I did npm install using a different nodejs version, 
try deleting node_modules folder installing and starting

```
cd your_project
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
npm start or gulp or whatever
```

If you are using nvm do

```
nvm use stable // or your favorite version
// remove node_module directory
npm install
npm start or gulp or whatever
```

Answer (score 15):

Try to add suffix --force

```
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

For my particular case none of the above answers worked. So what it worked:

```sh
rm -rf node_modules 
rm -rf /tmp/* 
rm -rf /root/.npm/node-sass 
npm uninstall --save node-sass 
npm cache clean --force
```

`npm cache verify` to check that nothing is left in the cache

```sh
npm install
```

Altough I haven't tried to reproduce the sequence it was a combination of the above that worked.
In addition you may also try:

`npm install --save node-sass` or `npm install node-sass -g`

```sh
npm rebuild node-sass
npm install bindings
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with Node v7.4.0 Current (Latest Features).

Did some reading here and downgraded Node to v6.9.4 LTS and after running `npm rebuild node-sass` it downloaded the binary and everything started working.

> Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-48_binding.node
>   Download complete .] - :
>   Binary saved to D:\xxx\xxx-xxx\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node
>   Caching binary to C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\3.13.1\win32-x64-48_binding.node`

Answer (score 6):

I'm a Windows 8 user, recently updated Node to `v8.11.1` and npm to `v6.0.0` and faced similar issue. Nothing worked - `npm install -g node-sass@latest` or deleting the `node-sass` directory from the project `node_modules/` - none of 'em worked for me.

The Laravel Mix was throwing an error to my browser console saying a missing node: `win32-x64-57`. I don't know whether it's because a slower internet connection or something, the node was missing during the update.

Hence some of the answers directed me to look at the Node-Sass releases, and I found the solution.

1. **Step 1:** Check your node-sass version using the command: `npm view node-sass version` (the `{your version}` in step 4)
2. **Step 2:** Get to [Node-Sass Releases](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases)
3. **Step 3:** Get your release and find the missing node in the assets listed under every release, and download the file
4. **Step 4:** Get to your PC's `C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\{your version}\` and put the downloaded `.node` file inside the version folder

And you are done.

In my case the node-sass version was `4.9.0` and the missing node was `win32-x64-57_binding.node`, so I downloaded the `.node` file from [4.9.0 release](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.9.0) and followed step 4.

Comment: Woaw... we got stuck on this for a full hour on a colleague's computer before finding this anwser. Nothing else worked, even trashing the whole node_modules directory. This completely solved the issue for us, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5):

For Visual Studio 2015/2017, Right Click on your `package.json` and Click on Restore Packages.

This will make sure that the npm from the Visual Studio Tools External Tools is run and the binding will be rebuild based on that.

Comment: Nice and easy solution, and the only one that worked from the few above that I tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I couldn't find any proper working solution in here, so I found mine:

Inspired by @Rob-Scott solution and other pointing that we could have 2 versions of Node.js installed, I went to `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs` and realized that I had a node.js version installed in addition to the VS default installation.

My solution was quite simple:

- Go to Tools > Options > Projects & solutions > Web package management > External web tools
- Click on `add an entry` (most left of the top-right block of buttons)
- Enter `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs`, validate by pressing `enter`
- Bring it at the top of the list
- Enjoy

Probably Node.js is not set well in the PATH variable, but this is my working very quick solution, my 2 cents :)

Answer (score 4):

This happens when in your workstation you run an update of Node.js and you are using node-sass globally.

So you should uninstall node-sass globally

```
npm uninstall -g node-sass
```

And then you have to install it globally, again

```
npm install -g node-sass
```

Comment: Good explanation!

Comment: @Fay007 could you provide more info? Do you have an error? Let me know

Answer (score 4):

The **post dependencies** for node-sass is **not getting installed** without the **package.json** inside **node-sass**

> Running it manually solved for me

```
node node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js
```

credit: [link](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1579#issuecomment-227602271)

Comment: Thanks for this, this solved my issue perfectly! :)

Comment: Glad to know :)

Answer (score 4):

Run the following commands, it works fine for me.

`npm install node-sass -g`

`npm rebuild node-sass`

`nvm use 10.16.3`

`node node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js`

`ng serve --poll=2000`

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:
`yarn add --force node-sass@4.14.1` or `yarn add --force node-sass`

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens because the environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Running `npm rebuild node-sass` builds the binding for the current environment.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a new directory in node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-46/ .
2. the download fil from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases
   (linux-x64-59_binding.node) based upon your version.
3. paste it in  node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-46/   rename  it to binding.node

Comment: although not a good practice, this solution might actually work (when all others fail) so when downvoting, it should be clarified why

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when upgrading from VS 2017 Professional to Enterprise

1. Close VS
2. Delete node_modules
3. Open VS
4. Right click package.json and select 'restore packages'

Comment: This is the safest approach for Visual Studio. Forget about all of these commands because they probably won't work. The commands have to be run from the *same* environment, which is the tricky part. Let visual studio do it and you're set.

Answer (score 3):

1. Delete node_modules folder.
2. Install dependencies again. (npm i)

Comment: This is only solution with npm or yarn.

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me nuts, and your solution fixed it for me!

Answer (score 3):

None of the install/rebuild solutions resolved the issue for me (using gulp).

Here is how I resolved it:

1) Download the missing binding file from the [repository](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-binaries).

2) Rename the file `binding.node`.

3) Create `node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-11` (path from error message) directory if it doesn't exist.

4) Add the binding file to `node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-11`

Answer (score 3):

Just refresh your npm cache and:

```
npm cache clean --force  
npm install
```

It always works for me in the same case.

**UPD:**  Your problem may also be by reason of absence of a global sasslib.

```
npm install -g sass
```

Answer (score 3):

Open Visual Studio 2017 
Go to Tools -> Options… 
Go to Projects and Solutions -> Web Package Management 
Move $(PATH) to the top of that list and close that window. 
Restart Visual Studio. 
This worked in my case, because my node version is 11.x

Comment: Definitely a valid answer when different projects use different bindings.
Executing `rebuild node-sass` was not enough. Changing the path priority fixed this.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have a build with different node version than the current one. Try running these commands and it should fix the issue.

```
npm cache clean --force &&  
rm -rf node_modules &&  
rm -rf package-lock.json &&  
npm i
```

Comment: This worked, but I believe line 3 should be `package-lock.json`. Concise and correct - many thanks.

Comment: That was a typo, updated command, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A similar error I encountered with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition while having created an AspNetCore app was:

```
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 32-bit with Node.js 5.x
Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x
This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports ([..]\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([..]\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([..]\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:187:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
```

You can see the from the error above that the cause was from a version mismatch on the bindings for nodejs.

> Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment:
>   **Windows 32-bit with Node.js 5.x**
>
> Found bindings for the following environments:
>     - **Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x**

The solution I found was to

- Install the [nodejs windows version](https://nodejs.org/en/),
- Add path for node js (C:\Program Files\nodejs) in External Web Tools (see Rob Scott's answer),
- Move nodejs path above $(PATH).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me 
Deleting `node_modules` and then restoring packages from IDE and then `npm rebuild node-sass`

Answer (score 2):

node-sass runs an install script to download the required binary. If there are no environment variables, .npmrc variables or process arguments set then the binary is determined by using the current process platform, architecture and Node ABI version. Therefore, if you run node install in one application and then try to run node-sass in an application with a different platform/architecture/ABI, the binary won't have been downloaded. The solution is to manually download the binary or to fix the binary version using an environment variable (SASS_BINARY_NAME) or a .npmrc variable (sass_binary_name)

You can see the logic for this in the getBinaryPath function in node-sass\lib\extensions.js

Answer (score 2):

I had to first choose the new default node version `nvm use ***` or `nvm install ***` and then remove all in node_modules in the project and `npm i` again.

Answer (score 2):

Just run the comment thats it.

**npm rebuild node-sass**

enjoy your coding...

Comment: The OP said he tried that and it didn't work. And so did I, and it didn't work for me either. Instead I had to downgrade the version of node I was running.

Comment: Actually not on linux ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

Just before removing your node_modules or clean your cache, which cost you time, try running

`npm rebuild node-sass --force`

in your project folder. Like mine, chance is high that your problem gets solved. In case it was not successful try the followings:

```
npm cache clean --force 
rm -rf node_modules 
npm install 
npm rebuild node-sass

npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

I just run npm rebuild instead of npm rebuild node-sass and issue gone.. I don't know what is the magic behind though.

Answer (score 1):

Please also remember to rename the xxx.node file ( in my case win32-x64-51) to binding.node and paste in the xxx folder ( in my case win32-x64-51),

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above, nothing worked, I was trying to match the node version to the node-sass version when I decided to go to the official node.js website, download the latest node version(currently v14 and I was on v12) and install it. This fixed my issue at last! It's possible that your node-sass version is ahead of your node.js version.

Answer (score 1):

I did all these in Linux Mint:

- Remove `node_modules`
- Ran `npm install`
- Ran `npm rebuild node-sass`

But it didn't fix the issue and still getting the error about node-sass.

I tried running again the command for rebuilding node-sass with sudo i.e. `sudo npm rebuild node-sass` and it worked finally!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when trying to use node-sass in docker on MacOS and none of the solutions here worked.

The error happened because I did an `npm install` before trying to build the docker image. The `npm install` was correctly pulling the MacOS version of node-sass into my node_modules and I was then copying the node_modules to my docker image running Linux. This fails because it can't run the MacOS version of node-sass on Linux.

In my case the solution was adding this to my makefile after the `npm install` step:

```
docker-compose run --rm --entrypoint "bash -c" mydockerimage "npm rebuild node-sass"
```

Comment: Hmmn I was having the error on My MacOs
```Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 16.x```
I ended up removing node_modules locally and ran the docker-comppose command. The docker was built successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Check your system: Does your system has 2 different `Node.js` installation?

If you install node from nodejs, the default installation directory is
`C:\Program Files\nodejs`
 I had the node version 6.xx installed here.

Check your VS External web tools directory
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Web\External`
I had the node version 5.xx installed there.

One  work around is :

- Make backup of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Web\External` directory.
- Copy `C:\Program Files\nodejs` directory content and
- paste into 
  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Web\External` Directory.
- Delete `node_modules` directory from your solution.
- Re run the project. 
  If you get error message re run the project second time.

If that does not work

- Delete `node_modules` directory from your solution.

NOTE: $ is the command prompt

```
$  npm install 
…
$ npm run build:dev
```

Rerun the project.

Answer (score 0):

For people that switched to nvm *from* system node, if you haven't removed the `~/.npm` and `~/.node-gyp` folder this problem can arise since perhaps the node version within `~/.node-gyp` *could* be different.

In any case those folders should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @core114 suggesting Uninstalling & installing `sass` package again works fine for manual process but for **automated deployment/CI/CD** you need more generic approach. What worked for me is for Continuos deployment of different environment is :

1. removing old `node_modules` using  `rimraf` before deployment

   rimraf node_modules
2. Updating `sass` package in npm `package.json` & committing to source control.

For next deployment it will automatically refresh sass for all environment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that the Task Runner Explorer was targeting the solution of my project. When I changed to the project itself using the drop-down list, next to the Task Runner Explorer refresh button, it showed the relevant tasks.

Answer (score 0):

When building a docker image and attempting to run it locally I ran into this same issue.  You need to add a .dockerignore file with the following:

`.DS_Store
.git
.gitignore
.idea
log/*
target
tmp
node_modules
client/node_modules
spec/internal/public/assets
public/assets`

Comment: Many people will probably not get this far down in the answers, but if anyone is getting this error in building a docker image and installing node, people are probably including node_modules from their host file system by mistake (a copy . . comand). A .dockerignore file with nodes_modules within it at the root project level will resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the maven-war-plugin that applied filters to the files and corrupted the woff files.

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <webResources>
        <resource>
            <directory>dist</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </webResources>
</configuration>
```

Remove <filtering>true</filtering>

Or if you need filtering you can do something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>dist</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>assets/**/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>dist</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>assets/**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all methods I've found.

I have noticed some strange behavior of that folder. When I was trying to "cd" to 'node_sass' folder from VS terminal, it told that "Folder was not found", but was seen in Finder.

chmod from VS terminal haven't find folder even with 'sudo' command.

I have chmod-ed from native MacOs terminal and just after have rebuild with node.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing JAVA_HOME from x86 to x64. Maven was running on x86 but node was using x64. Remove /node and /node_modules and build again.

Answer (score 0):

Please write below command on Root Folder.

npm rebuild node-sass

100% works...

Comment: Actually not on linux ubuntu 20.04 .

Answer (score 0):

This is something that may not happen to anyone else, but in my case, this error appeared when I decided to restart my project (to follow a different vue.js tutorial).

The steps that created my problem was:

```
# move my existing project
mv project-name project-name-old
# create a new project
vue create project-name
# run server
npm run server
```

The problem was that my previous server was still running on a different terminal tab. On localhost:8080, the page that was still showing was the old project.

All I had to do was shut down the old server in the terminal and execute "npm run serve" again (or view localhost:8081).

Just in case this confounds someone else for half an hour, or for laughs and giggles.

Answer (score 0):

remove the /node-modules folder  and install it again or run the gradle task deploy after it removed

/Users/warren/Sites/random-docs/my-cms/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-11/binding.node

It solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10
This was a fun one for me...
In order to resolve it I had to do all of the following..
1.) Apparently node-sass isn't supported by some of the more recent versions of Node.js
so I had to Uninstall Node-v 12.14.1, and delete the nodejs directory in C:/Program Files.
2.) Reinstall a earlier version of Node (for me 10.16.2 worked). NOTE: I had initially downloaded the x86 version so if your System is x64 download the x64 verison...
3.) From here I had to delete my entire project and re-clone it. After this things ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

On linux ubuntu 20.04 I needed few  steps,downgrade node first to apropriate version,remove node_modules,run yarn install and finally run `sudo yarn add node-sass@4.13.0 --force`.Node version 10.0.0.
Only working way for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your version of npm is the same that you project require to

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that the node-sass version in package-lock.json was different from the node-sass version in package.json. This steps solves my problem.

1. delete folder node-modules
2. delete package-lock.json
3. install python 2.7
4. add C:/Python27;C:/Python27/Scripts to Environment Variable -> Path
5. in Powershell, run as administrator -> npm install -g node-gyp
6. in my working folder -> npm install

Hope this works for you too

Answer (score 0):

I, just for adding  i was on Windows and i resolved my issue by removing the node-sass entry in my **user's** **node_module** folder (C:/users/$username/node_modules/node_sass )

Rebuilding and removing node_sass did nothing before and now my issue is resolved !

Answer (score 0):

Further to [Abdelsalam Megahed's brief answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70080665/1447509), which contained most of the solution... *(i.e. view his answer and do that first)*

After following the four short steps Abdelsalam suggested, I ran `npm run dev` and received the following message:

```
Failed to load C:\path\tsconfig.json: Missing baseUrl in compilerOptions
```

The final step was to edit the tsconfig.json file and add `"baseURL": ".",`, under `"compilerOptions":`, like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    etc etc etc
```

The problem was resolved at this point.

*Note: It may be necessary to hard-reset <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> the page to see the change (even with nodemon).*

Answer (score 0):

If you got to the end of this thread, and things are still not working. It may be silly, but try verifying if you have any of these files in your folder:

- .node-version
- .nvmrc

They are the culprit of why things are not working for you. Update the files with the node version, and then re-run the procedure others provided in this thread. It will work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for a long time while locally running a build in Docker, using a node alpine image. I was using the following to create the base layer:

```
FROM node:19.4-alpine3.17 AS node_base
RUN apk update && \
    apk add python3 make && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

There was one package it was missing: `g++`. Changing the above to the following, did the trick for me:

```
FROM node:19.4-alpine3.17 AS node_base
RUN apk update && \
    apk add python3 make g++ && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

I believe this is somehow linked with the architecture of the macbook PRO with M1 chip, and I wouldn't encounter this error in other machines, but I haven't tested.

Answer (score -1):

For me, when i ran npm install it audited the installed packages and showed "found 1 high severity vulnerability" and by running

```
npm audit fix
```

did the trick. Posting if it helps someone.

Update: Sharing my error log:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Missing binding ..\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
....
```

It did ask me to

```
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
```

Comment: This is not what the question is about.

Answer (score -1):

Install Xcode if you are on a mac.

Answer (score -2):

For Mac:

1. -CMD+SHIFT+G
2. -/usr/local/lib/node-sass
3. -right click and renamed: should still the same node-sass
4. -then run: npm install node-sass -g

that fixed.