# CSS modules not working in Codesandbox - can't find files even though they exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, codesandbox

I'm trying to build a project and I just moved my code from VSCode to Codesandbox. I must mention that the code was working fine in VSC but for some reason it's not working in Codesandbox - the CSS modules can't be found. I am thinking I am maybe missing something in my setup since I looked at other examples and the code seems identical (the imports). The error in getting for all the files is:

```
Cannot find module './Example.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

The complete code is here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/burger-builder-project-173uw?file=/src/Components/Layout/Layout.tsx

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't import CSS/SCSS modules. TypeScript says "Cannot Find Module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382842/cant-import-css-scss-modules-typescript-says-cannot-find-module)

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of the error you need to create a [Typescript Declaration file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html) for `*.css` on the root folder and include it on the `tsconfig.json`. Take a look on the changes below:

**module.css.d.ts**

```js
declare module "*.module.css";
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
    "include": [
        "./src/*",
        "./module.css.d.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015"
        ],
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to fix this (that's how I work with CSS files):

```
// Layout.tsx

import React from "react";
import BurgerBuilder from "../../ContainerBurgerBuilder";

// CSS
import "./Layout.module.css";
```

And then in your `render` method:

```
render() {
   return (
      <div className="Content">
         <BurgerBuilder/>
      </div>

   );
}
```

Comment: My code, surprisingly, seems to be working, I just can't get rid of the error. Your solution breaks the whole app. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. I hope you will find a more suitable solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

enable javascript in your html file, then i think it will work

Comment: It's a comment.

Answer (score 0):

add "Typescript Plugin Css Modules" from your dependency list in codesandbox.io

[image]

[image]