# NextJs build fails, while development server runs fine

Tags: reactjs, typescript, less, next.js

I have a NextJs application with custom less configuration:

```
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const withLess = require("@zeit/next-less");
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const basePath = process.env.BASE_PATH || '';

// fix: prevents error when .less files are required by node
if (typeof require !== "undefined") {
  require.extensions[".less"] = (file) => {};
}

module.exports = withCSS({
  // basePath: basePath,
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
  },
  ...withLess(
    withSass({
      lessLoaderOptions: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
    })
  ),
});
```

running a dev build using `npm run dev` works just fine, while running `npm run build` results in the following error:

```
./src/pages\index.tsx:2:20
Type error: Cannot find module '../../styles/Home.module.less' or its corresponding type declarations.

  1 | import Head from 'next/head'
> 2 | import styles from '../../styles/Home.module.less'
    |                    ^
  3 | import PageLayout from './layout'
  4 | 
  5 | export default function Home(props) {
info  - Creating an optimized production build .
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Try to remove `.less` extension

Comment: Now it fails even in dev.

Comment: I'd willing to bet that this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382842/cant-import-css-scss-modules-typescript-says-cannot-find-module

Comment: You just need to declare typings for `.less` modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggested, there was a delcaration for the Typescript compiler missing:

```
///declaration.d.ts
declare module '*.less' {
    const resource: { [key: string]: string };
    export = resource;
}
```

and the according reference in tsconfig.json:

```
"include": [
    "node_modules/@types",
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "declaration.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
```