# Directly imported CSS file from node modules oddly go missing

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-dev-server, css-loader

I got hit with a very peculiar problem when trying to import a CSS file from a node module.

In my `App.tsx` file, I have

```
import './App.css';                       // works
import '@foo/my-dependency/dist/foo.css'; // doesn't work
```

While importing local CSS file works nicely, importing `foo.css` from a node module does not work at all, yet no compilation error is observed.

And if I change that line to `require` syntax, it works normally.

```
require('@foo/my-dependency/dist/foo.css'); // works
```

And if I change it to CSS module like syntax, it works as well.

```
import style from '@foo/my-dependency/dist/foo.css'; // works
console.log(style);     // to ensure the imported stuff is used at least once
```

Note to support above I need to add CSS module type declaration as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41946697/4993386).

I am not sure where exactly it is going wrong. My Webpack config on module rules looks like below. And I use webpack dev server for testing. Webpack version is 5.23.0.

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx?|tsx?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I get really surprised how good I am at tripping myself over. This is caused by a `sideEffects: false` setting I put into the `package.json` file of my dependency package to support Webpack tree shaking. It is specifically mentioned in the [doc](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free) that `css/scss` files need to be marked as side effects in case they get pruned as an unwanted result. After changing to `sideEffects: ["*.css"]` everything works.

It's no surprise either that the other two working solutions I listed above are valid because when Webpack does tree shaking, it traverses through the `import` statements starting from the entry file. If it's not an `import` statement or the imported stuff is specifically used, surely tree shaking won't take effect.

Comment: Adding my 2 cents.. I was using postcss on the library which uses inject. That converted the imports to `"../file.css.js"` so I had to use `sideEffects: ["*.css.js"]` for it to work.