# Cannot find module 'module.css' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript

Don't know why typescript suddenly not recogize my code, it show

```
Cannot find module './hookStyle/useMemostyle.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations
```

It happen when i move style to another folder

Here is typescript config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "lib",
    "removeComments": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "sourceRoot": "/",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*"
  ]
}
```

It not effect the code, it still working but why typescript show that error? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To import custom file types, you must use [TypeScript's `declare module` syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) to let it know that it's ok to import.  To do this, simply create a `globals.d.ts` (declaration file) wherever your other code's root directory is and then add in this code:

```
declare module '*.css';
```

You may also need to add the path to `"globals.d.ts"` into the `"include"` property in your `tsconfig.json` file if this still does not work (Thanks to @Ash Archin for this advice).

Comment: For me this file should also add as "globals.d.ts" in the include property in tsconfig.json

Comment: Put the 'globals.d.ts' into the src folder of your project.

Comment: If it does not help, check if globals.d.ts is included in tsconfig.json & try removing imports in globals.d.ts. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382842/cant-import-css-scss-modules-typescript-says-cannot-find-module/75069542#75069542

Comment: @AshArchin thats probably a very important piece of this pie.  Can we add that on the answer solution statement above... ?

Comment: I added Ash's advice to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative solution that worked for me was to install an additional TypeScript types dependency; [@types/css-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/css-modules), to automatically add type-safe import definitions for the following style modules:

- `*.css`
- `*.scss`
- `*.sass`
- `*.less`
- `*.styl`

The list above may become out-of-date over time, and so you may view the [latest](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/css-modules/index.d.ts) supported type-safe style module imports.

That was all that was needed to resolve the TS lint error for being unable to find the CSS module, without needing to having to create any declaration file (e.g. `*.d.ts`).

Here is the command you may like to try and use to install the dependency locally to your project:

```bash
npm install --save-dev @types/css-modules
```

If after checking over the [latest](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/css-modules/index.d.ts) up-to-date style modules that are currently supported by the dependency, and you feel it is legitimately missing a declaration for particular a style module, then feel free to contribute to and extend the `@types/css-modules` type dependency project, which is maintained within the open-source [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) GitHub repository.