# Declaration type to use CSS file import (tippy.js)

Tags: css, typescript, styled-components, storybook, tippyjs

I'm trying to use tippy.js css in my project in storybook / typescript / styled-components

I import the css file in my styled-component but I typescript ask me declaration type to use it.

`Cannot find module 'tippy.js/themes/material.css' or its corresponding type declarations.`

This is my styled-component file :

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

import Tippy from '@tippyjs/react';
import tippyCss from 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css';
import tippyMaterialCss from 'tippy.js/themes/material.css';

export const TooltipStyle = styled(Tippy)`
${tippyCss}
${tippyMaterialCss}
`;
```

Do you know what i should put in the declaration type file ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try importing the stylesheet in the document head?

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="tippy.js/themes/material.css">`

Edit: That was my very first comment. If for some reason the 'typescript' module controls .css file imports:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41946697/17449845

This response contains a few lines of code pertaining to declaring modules in Typescript.