# TypeScript only complains module not found for css modules while .d.ts file is closed in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an issue very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382842/cant-import-css-scss-modules-typescript-says-cannot-find-module), where a "cannot find module" error is thrown when trying to import CSS modules. However, the suggested answer to that question is to create a `declaration.d.ts` file like the following:

```typescript
declare module "*.sass" // or .css or .scss, I am using sass
```

This works—kind of. For some reason, VSCode shows me the error *only when the .d.ts file is not open*. If I keep the declaration file open all the time, no error is shown. However, I obviously don't want to keep the file open all the time, and I would like to just get it to work.

Does anyone know a fix to this problem in VSCode? Perhaps a setting or an extension?

Additional information:

- VSCode version: 1.65.2
- OS: Mac OS Big Sur

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same exact issue when closing my `declaration.d.ts` file - I just moved `declaration.d.ts` to inside my `src` folder and it went away

Comment: Hmm, I’ll check this out. I haven’t been using CSS modules recently but I’ll check if the problem still occurs with your fix.