# Cannot find module './styles.scss' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass

i install

`yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript`

`yarn add sass`

**App.tsx**

```
import styles from "./styles.scss";

function App() {
  return <div className={styles.App}></div>;
}

export default App;
```

**styles.scss**

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}
```

both files in the same folder

when i want to import, i get this error

> Cannot find module './styles.scss' or its corresponding type declarations

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think this might answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382842/cant-import-css-scss-modules-typescript-says-cannot-find-module

Comment: I do not know what the problem is, I have tried it many times but it did not work, but now it has earned

Answer (score 2):

this problem is because you install typescript on existed react-app.

first put a "declarations.d.ts" in your project and add the following line-code to it:

```
declare module '*.scss';
```