# Node/Docker is node-sass not finding installed bindings (via Webpack)

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack-dev-server, node-sass, webpack-style-loader

I'm struggling to get the webpack dev server setup in a docker container based on `node:latest`

Despite trying all the various incantations in [Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986800/node-sass-could-not-find-a-binding-for-your-current-environment), I keep getting the same error:

```
web_1         | ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/sass/style.sass
web_1         | Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /prject/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-59/binding.node
web_1         | Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 9.x
web
```

here's the current

```
# Dockerfile
RUN yarn cache clean && yarn install --non-interactive --force
RUN rm -rf node_modules/node_sass
RUN npm rebuild node-sass
```

the rebuild step suggests that the binary *is* installed and checks out:

```
Binary found at /advocate/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-59/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
```

Also confusing to me is that I do get this

```
web_1         | Found bindings for the following environments:
web_1         |   - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 7.x
```

which makes me think it's using the host platform in some capacity that I don't quite follow.

Comment: Try adding `node_modules` to your `.dockerignore` file. The install will take a bit longer but you should not get any cross over between your dev environment and container.

Comment: I did this, and for like 12 hours it was working, but now the same error has returned (no doubt due to _something_ I did in the intervening time)... Is it possible a `docker-compose` volume entry is the culprit? `- ../code-frontend/:/code/` ... initial tests (commenting out said line and rebuilding) suggest so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The state of the `node_modules` directory is being taken from the development host into the container. This is an issue when platform based decisions have been made during an `npm/yarn install`, normally  modules that use native code.

### Dockerfile builds

Add `node_modules` to your `.dockerignore` file. The install will take a bit longer in the container but you should never get any cross over between your dev environment and container.

### Mounted Development Volumes

Mounting your development code with `node_modules` into the container can also cause the same problems. Running a `yarn install --force` on the new platform before using it should normally be enough to switch it over/back.

There's not a simple way to ignore a directory when mounting a volume. You could mount every directory/file in your project individually and then ignore `node_modules` but that's a lot of work.

### Syncing Development Volumes

This is a way to avoid mounting volumes. [docker-sync](http://docker-sync.io/) has an [`rsync` strategy](https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/wiki/8.-Strategies#rsync-osx) that can ignore files. This might also speed some apps up that have heavy file access patterns. File access is slow on volumes mounted from osx > vm > docker.

```
version: '2'

options:
  verbose: true

syncs:
  yourproject_data:
    sync_strategy: 'rsync'
    src: './'
    sync_host_port: 10872
    sync_args: '-v' 
    sync_excludes:
      - '.sass-cache/'
      - 'sass-cache/'
      - 'vendor/'
      - 'bower_components/'
      - 'node_modules/'
      - '.git/'
```

File deletion doesn't sync to the container by default though, which you need to take into consideration. I do an occasional delete of the synced volume when I need things cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

try this command:

sudo npm -g config set user root

I have the same problem. Fixed by set the npm user to the root user.