# Adding gulp-sass breaks by task runner

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have a basic gulp setup in VS2017 to minify my Javascript. I decided to add gulp-sass (my package.json says I'm on gulp-sass v4.0.1) but it throws this error:

```
C:\Work\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:66
    let sassMap;
    ^^^
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Work\MyProject\MyProject\gulpfile.js:11:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
```

My gulpfile looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('minify', function () {
    gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
        .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('Content'));


});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('src/css/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('Content'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['minify']);
});
```

I did some Googling and a simple fix suggested was to add "use strict" to the top of the offending file, in this case index.js:66. However, after doing that I get:

```
Failed to run "C:\Work\MyProject\MyProject\Gulpfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
C:\Work\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15
      throw new Error(errors.missingBinary());
      ^
Error: Missing binding C:\Work\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-47\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 5.x
Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x
This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (C:\Work\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Work\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Work\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:163:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
```

I am running Node.js v6. I'm lost as to why what should be a simple process is giving me these errors. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**:

I ran the following commands suggested in the comments:

```
npm install node-sass -f
npm rebuild nose-sass
```

Both ran successfully. However, I'm still getting this error:

```
Failed to run "C:\Work\MyProject\MyProject\Gulpfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
C:\Work\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:66
    let sassMap;
    ^^^
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Work\MyProject\MyProject\gulpfile.js:8:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
```

**Update 2:**

I was advised to add "use strict"; to the top of my gulpfile.js, but the same error occurs. Here's the file contents:

```
"use strict";
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass'); // If I comment this out, I can build

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('src/css/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('Content'));
});
```

[image]

Most common issue online appears to be Node.js version of < 6.0, but I'm running v6.11.1.

### **Update 3: (solved)**

I *finally* found the cause & solution; I've added it as an answer down below for any future readers. Enjoy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986800/node-sass-could-not-find-a-binding-for-your-current-environment

Comment: `npm rebuild node-sass` or `npm install node-sass -f` will rebuild the binaries or (the second) force node sass to reinstall.

Comment: @muecas Thanks for the suggestions. I've updated the question as I'm now getting a different error, which is the error I was getting before I went poking around in /node_modules/gulp-sass - reinstalling must have fixed the issued I caused, and now I've returned to the original problem. Could you have another look?

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara Thanks, I've updated the question with my new error

Comment: @MSOACC you need to add `"use strict";` at the top of your js gulp file.

Comment: @muecas Still gives me the exact same error. If I comment out the "var sass = require('gulp-sass');" line in gulpfile.js I can at least build, but as soon as that's uncommented it gives me the same error I mentioned. I'll update the question with my exact gulpfile.js contents just so you can see

Comment: OK I managed to fix it myself. Can't believe more people have'n't had this error; I'll write an answer for future people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Managed to find the problem so I'm answering my own question for future readers.

Whilst I have node.js v6.11.1 installed, Visual Studio 2017 comes bundled with it's own version of node that it uses by default. Even if you run `node -v` in the VS2017 shell and it tells you it's running v6.11.1, it's actually - by default - running whatever it finds in `.\node_mobules\.bin`.

The solution is this:

1. In VS2017, go "Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools".
2. You'll probably see this:

[image]

3. Add the path to your standalone installation of node (default `C:\Program Files\nodejs`) and, using the arrows, position it above the `.\node_modules\bin` version, like this:

[image]

4. Hit OK and either refresh the Task Runner Explorer or restart VS2017. Your gulpfile should now build.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to move $(PATH) above $(VSINSTALLDIR)/Web/External to fix the problem.