# Unable to use node-sass with Windows 64-bit with Node.js 10.x?

Tags: node.js, gulp-sass, node-sass

I'm using Node.js 10 which is the recommended version and just trying to run a simple gulp task to compile some SCSS files. However, I am getting the following error.

> Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment:
>   Windows 64-bit with Node.js 10.x Found bindings for the following
>   environments:
>     - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

Full error here

```
Failed to run "C:\Users\lee\Documents\Projects\Merch.Umb\Src\Merch.Web\Gulpfile.js"... cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple C:\Users\lee\Documents\Projects\Merch.Umb\Src\Merch.Web\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15
      throw new Error(errors.missingBinary());
      ^ Error: Missing binding C:\Users\lee\Documents\Projects\Merch.Umb\Src\Merch.Web\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-64\binding.node Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 10.x Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 8.x This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`. Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (C:\Users\lee\Documents\Projects\Merch.Umb\Src\Merch.Web\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lee\Documents\Projects\Merch.Umb\Src\Merch.Web\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lee\Documents\Projects\Merch.Umb\Src\Merch.Web\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:162:21)
```

Am I supposed to uninstall v10 and install an older version of Node.Js?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the node_modules folder and run `npm install`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986800/node-sass-could-not-find-a-binding-for-your-current-environment)

Answer (score 3):

***I think this can solve you problem.***

By going into project folder till the location of node-sass folder and then execute:

```
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

**Alternative is**

Delete `node-saas` and Do

`npm install`

Comment: Tried both and neither fixes it.

Comment: Try to do it with --force flag

Comment: Tried that, again, makes no difference.

Comment: changing the the npm registry, so you can bring from other server. npm config set registry https://registry.npm.taobao.org/ . taobao is useful when europeans servers are collapsing.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall node and use Node.js version manager (**nvm**) for Windows to install the latest NodeJs version.

Delete node_modules and rebuild with **npm install**.