# NodeJS App Deployment via Azure DevOps 32bit issue

Tags: node.js, sass, azure-devops

i am using Azure DevOps Build & Release to build my node.js react app that uses node-sass. So the Build is using the Node.js Tool Installer to specify the node.js version and then runs the npm install command. It all runs with a hosted agent that requires node.js and npm. The azure app service which runs the application is a default windows site.
After that i want to deploy it via Azure DevOps Release. I am using the Task "App Service Deploy" to deploy it. If i don't specify a deployment method it uses "Run from Package" and everything is fine. (Except that i cannot make changes in the root folder, but thats the concept of the run from package). If i change it to deploy via "Zip Deploy" i get the following error:

> Error: Missing binding
>   D:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-57\binding.node
>   Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment:
>   Windows 32-bit with Node.js 8.x Found bindings for the following
>   environments: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

So i got this one already in my dev environment, but there i could get a simple workaround - install and use the 32bit version of node.js and then deploy it to azure (via VS Code extension). Now it is not possible to use 32bit nodejs in the Azure DevOps Build task as i saw as a limitation of the windows app services in azure.

How can i get Azure DevOps to use 32 bit when using npm install? Is the only possible way to switch to a linux app service (which runs 64bit) in azure?

Thanks!

Comment: You can take a look at this case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986800/node-sass-could-not-find-a-binding-for-your-current-environment?page=1&tab=oldest#tab-top and see if there is any help to you.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what i've already found. WIth this i fixed it on my local environment with the help of node.js 32bit. The problem that i have is that all hosted agents are running 64 bit of node js but the deploy works via the Azure App Service Deploy task, which uses the site to deploy all the content which than uses 32bit which leads to the posted error.