# I get this error while compiling the code, I have copied the code from another system. How can I solve this error?

Tags: node.js, angular, sass

ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Missing binding E:\Angular App\Client\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-64\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (E:\Angular App\Client\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:13)
    at Object. (E:\Angular App\Client\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.sassLoader (E:\Angular App\Client\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:72)
ERROR in ./src/app/core/preloader/preloader.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/app/core/preloader/preloader.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Missing binding E:\Angular App\Client\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-64\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node Sass couldn't find a binding for your current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986800/node-sass-couldnt-find-a-binding-for-your-current-environment)

Answer (score 0):

Your error literally says:

```
Run npm rebuild node-sass
```