# Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 32-bit with Node.js 12.x

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, node-modules, node-sass

When I try to compile my sass files (`node-sass -o css/ css/`) I run into `Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment` error. I followed similiar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986800/node-sass-couldnt-find-a-binding-for-your-current-environment) and none of npm scripts mentioned solve the problem like `npm rebuild node-sass`, or deleting `node_modules` and run `npm install`.

I read in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986800/node-sass-couldnt-find-a-binding-for-your-current-environment/41304976#41304976) that if none of npm scripts solve the problem, then you have to download the missed binding and place it in the appropriate destination folder.

In my case the missed binding is `linux-ia32-72_binding.node` as mentioned in the error message

```
Error: Missing binding /home/saad/Documents/bOGnMCzEEeiTdA5yoE99Fg_6da6f2f02cc411e8b484f7e801bd0278_Bootstrap4-starter/Bootstrap4/conFusion/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-ia32-72/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 32-bit with Node.js 12.x
```

The problem is that I don't find that binding [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-binaries) to download it! the last version I found was `linux-ia32-51_binding.node`!

I can't compile my sass files now, and I forced to compile it online, how can I solve this?

Note: npm version is `npm@7.0.5` and node version `node@v12.18.4`

Update: When I run `uname -m` the output is `x86_64` which means that my linux is 64-bit, so why the error said `Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 32-bit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node no longer supports x86 in v10 and above, so node-sass has no "ia32" for Node 12 (72). You can see the supported minimum node-sass versions here https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy

Comment: So if I installed node v8 it may works for my 32-bit system?

Comment: Yes, except that Node 8 is end of life now